# Rendering family tree graph

Tags: 7, views

My website has a bunch of nodes of content type `member`, and to each node is associated 0 or more other `member` nodes via a field `field_big_brother_s_`. How do I use [graphviz](https://www.drupal.org/project/graphviz) to render this information into a graph. I don't need the graph to be dynamic, and it doesn't need to be rendered on-demand (since the database is only updated a few times a year).

I've tried to look into the [Graphviz Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/graphviz_filter) module, but being someone new to Drupal, I have no idea how to use it or even whether it's still usable.

Comment: The graphviz module never made it out of dev (development); thus, very unlikely that its usable. Hopefully, someone can provide you with an alternative.